# Get all child element values of specific node using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm using XPath to read elements from an XML document. Specifically I want to return the values of any element which is the child of a specified element (here the specified element is `<SceneryType>` and these elements have single-digit values. So I want to return all of the children of `<SceneryType> 1` for example.

Here is the XML:

```
<MissionObjectives>
<Theme themeName="Gothic">
    <SceneryType>
    1
        <Objective>
        Do a river thing.
        </Objective>
        <Objective>
        Get all men to the other side of the river.
        </Objective>
    </SceneryType>
    <SceneryType>
    2
        <Objective>
        Climb some trees!
        </Objective>
        <Objective>
        Shoot the tree!
        </Objective>
    </SceneryType>
</Theme>
```

I've tried various ways of getting these child elements, but I can't figure it out. My //objective part of the expression just returns everything from the root it seems, but the iterator isn't running which seems odd, shouldn't it loop through every element if the expression is returning a nodelist of all the elements?

```
XPathDocument missionDoc = new XPathDocument(objectivesPath + "MissionObjectives" + chosenTheme + ".xml");

XPathNavigator nav = missionDoc.CreateNavigator();

foreach (Scenery scenery in world.currentWorld)
{
    int sceneryType = scenery.type;

    XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile($"MissionObjectives/Theme/SceneryType[text()='{sceneryType}']//Objective");

    XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);

    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        XPathNavigator nav2 = iterator.Current.Clone();
        compatibleObjectivesList.Add(nav2.Value);
    }
}
```

I've tried looking through Stack Overflow for similar questions but I can't seem to find anything which applies to XPath. I can't use LINQ to XML for this. Any idea how I can return all the values of the various 'Objective' nodes?

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its much simpler to use the XDocument:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(objectivesPath + "MissionObjectives" + chosenTheme + ".xml");
```

to get all of the first SceneryType child nodes:

```
var node = doc.XPathSelectElement("//MissionObjectives/Theme/SceneryType[1]");
```

to get the second objective node:

```
var node = doc.XPathSelectElement("//MissionObjectives/Theme/SceneryType/Objective[2]");
```

more [xpath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) samples

Comment: Great, this (plus some cheeky loops) is exactly what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For one, your xml data has carriage returns, line feeds, and white spaces in the search element's text node.  Keep in mind, that an XML node can be an element, attribute, or text (among other node types).  The solution below is a bit on the "long-handed" side and perhaps a little "hacky", but it should work.  I wasn't certain if you wanted the child element text data or the entire child element, but I return just the child text node data (without carriage returns and line feeds).  Also, while this solution DOES NOT use LINQ to XML in the strictest sense, it does use one LINQ expression.

```
    private List<string> getSceneryTypeObjectiveTextList(string xml, int sceneryTypeId, string xpath = "/MissionObjectives/Theme/SceneryType")
    {
        List<string> result = null;
        XmlDocument doc = null;
        XmlNodeList sceneryTypeNodes = null;

        try
        {
            doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            sceneryTypeNodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);

            if (sceneryTypeNodes != null)
            {
                if (sceneryTypeNodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode sceneryTypeNode in sceneryTypeNodes)
                    {
                        if (sceneryTypeNode.HasChildNodes)
                        {
                            var textNode = from XmlNode n in sceneryTypeNode.ChildNodes
                                           where (n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text && n.Value.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "") == sceneryTypeId.ToString())
                                           select n;

                            if (textNode.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                XmlNodeList objectiveNodes = sceneryTypeNode.SelectNodes("Objective");

                                if (objectiveNodes != null)
                                {
                                    result = new List<string>(objectiveNodes.Count);

                                    foreach (XmlNode objectiveNode in objectiveNodes)
                                    {
                                        result.Add(objectiveNode.InnerText.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Trim());
                                    }

                                    // Could break out of the iteration, here, if we know that SceneryType is always unique (i.e. - no duplicates in Element text node)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle error
        }
        finally
        {

        }

        return result;
    }


    private sampleCall(string filePath, int sceneryTypeId)
    {
        List<string> compatibleObjectivesList = null;

        try
        {
            compatibleObjectivesList = getSceneryTypeObjectiveTextList(File.ReadAllText(filePath), sceneryTypeId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
    // Handle error
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```